# Finding statistically significant favorites among objects

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm designing an experiment where subjects are asked to choose their favorite object among 3 different objects. Each subject gets the same 3 objects to choose from. How can I determine if one of the objects is favorited over the other objects in this experiment? The data looks like this:

```
Subject  Object 1  Object 2   Object 3
1        0         0          1
2        1         0          0
3        1         0          0
4        0         1          0
5        1         0          0
...
```

A 1 denotes that a particular object was a favorite. As an example, Subject 4's favorite object was Object 2.

I also have a small sample size, ~20-35 subjects (class room size), so any techniques for dealing with small samples would be desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each classroom, or for the total, you could do one way chi square tests.

First, find the total number of preferences for each object. Suppose in classroom 1 it is (10, 5, 15). Then do the test. If you have `R` you can use

```
chisq.test(c(10,5,15), simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

If you are doing it by hand, you will have to rely on asymptotic theory and compute

$\sum(O-E)^2/E$

where O is observed and E is expected (which, for you, would be equal counts). In the example I gave this would be

$\frac{(10-10)^2 + (5-10)^2 + (15-10)^2)}{10} = \frac{50}{10}$ you can then look up the p value in a chi-square table with df = 2 (one less than the number of objects), or find the value through an online calculator.